# Adding multiple filtering to a Kendo Grid via checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid for records that have four status types: "scheduled", "open", "on execution" and "closed".

[image]

I am trying to use the checkboxes as filters so I can show only the statuses I need. I know how to set one single filter, for example, list only the "scheduled" records, or the "closed" ones. But I want to show the "scheduled" and "open" records, for example, and I haven't figured out how. What I have right now works for a single status type.

Here's some code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var ck_scheduled = $('#ck_scheduled').prop('checked');
    var ck_open = $('#ck_open').prop('checked');
    var ck_onexecution = $('#ck_onExecution').prop('checked');
    var ck_closed = $('#ck_closed').prop('checked');
    var allFilters = [];

    if (ck_scheduled) {
        allFilters.push({ logic: "or", field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Scheduled" });
    }
    if (ck_open) {
        allFilters.push({ logic: "or", field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Open" });
    }
    if (ck_onexecution) {
        allFilters.push({ logic: "or", field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "On execution" });
    }
    if (ck_closed) {
        allFilters.push({ logic: "or", field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Closed" });
    }
    grid.dataSource.filter(allFilters);
});
```

What I'm trying to do with this function here is: when one of the checkboxes change, it will check the 4 checkboxes state and add a filter (using the "or" logical operator) for the checked ones. In the end, apply all the filters.

But what is happening: it only applies one filter. For example, when I check the "closed" checkbox, it shows only "closed" records, ignoring the other checked checkboxes.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.logic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a mistake when setting the `logic` in the filters. `logic` is defined globally for all filter conditions. I.e. either set an `and` or an `or` of the filter conditions. Not for each condition.

The `change` event handler should look like:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var ck_scheduled = $('#ck_scheduled').prop('checked');
    var ck_open = $('#ck_open').prop('checked');
    var ck_onexecution = $('#ck_onExecution').prop('checked');
    var ck_closed = $('#ck_closed').prop('checked');
    var allFilters = [];

    if (ck_scheduled) {
        allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Scheduled" });
    }
    if (ck_open) {
        allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Open" });
    }
    if (ck_onexecution) {
        allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "On execution" });
    }
    if (ck_closed) {
        allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Closed" });
    }
    grid.dataSource.filter({ logic: "or", filters: allFilters});
});
```

```js
var ds = [
  { Code: "c1", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "scheduled" },
  { Code: "c2", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "open" },
  { Code: "c3", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "onexecution" },
  { Code: "c4", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "closed" },
  { Code: "c5", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "open" },
  { Code: "c6", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "open" },
  { Code: "c7", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "on execution" },
  { Code: "c8", Date: "2014/01/01", Status: "on execution" }
];

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: ds,
  columns   :
  [
    { field: "Code" },
    { field: "Date"}, 
    { field: "Status" }
  ]
}).data("kendoGrid");

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var ck_scheduled = $('#ck_scheduled').prop('checked');
  var ck_open = $('#ck_open').prop('checked');
  var ck_onexecution = $('#ck_onExecution').prop('checked');
  var ck_closed = $('#ck_closed').prop('checked');
  var allFilters = [];

  if (ck_scheduled) {
    allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Scheduled" });
  }
  if (ck_open) {
    allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Open" });
  }
  if (ck_onexecution) {
    allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "On execution" });
  }
  if (ck_closed) {
    allFilters.push({ field: "Status", operator: "eq", value: "Closed" });
  }
  grid.dataSource.filter({ logic: "or", filters: allFilters});

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<label>Scheduled: <input type="checkbox" id="ck_scheduled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<label>Open: <input type="checkbox" id="ck_open"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<label>On Execution: <input type="checkbox" id="ck_onExecution"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<label>Closed: <input type="checkbox" id="ck_closed"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<div id="grid"></div>
```